# How do I change the color of a selected label in Ionic?

Tags: ionic-framework

I want to change the color of the selected label. I'm using --color-selected in CSS, but it doesn't work.

**Html**

```
  <ng-container *ngFor="let item of daily"> 
        <ion-label id="daysName" class="favorites-label" (click)="dayName($event)">{{item.day}}</ion-label>   
      </ng-container>
```

**TS**

```
 dayName($event) {
    console.log('dayName', $event.target.innerHTML)
}
```

**CSS**

```
   #daysName {
        color: white;
        --color-selected: red;
    }
    ion-label.favorites-label {
        --color-selected: red;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ngClass:

```
[ngClass]="{'favorites-label': step === 'step1'}"
```

Or

```
[class.favorites-labels] = "step === 'step1'"
```